# How to configure WebStorm for firebase use?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, webstorm

I've been looking around for an answer, but failed to find one.

I can't seem to understand how to configure my WebStorm properly for my html+javascript project, so it compiles and debugs correctly.
I've tried clicking yellow tooltips next to `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>`
 and downloading libraries, but that doesn't help. Setting up library manually by going into settings - > javascript - > libraries and adding firebase.js also doesn't help.

After running the code, all I'm getting is:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
^

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
```

I didn't see a single thing concerning this on web, am I doing something wrong, or..?

Comment: make sure you call `firebase.initializeApp` **after** loading `firebase.js`

Comment: this is runtime error not related to WebStorm. How do you run your code? Does it work when running it outside of WebStorm?

Comment: Uhm.. i'm quite new to Javascript, but if you mean if my javascript works when i'm launching HTML in browser, it doesn't show any errors.